# How to configure Apache NiFi for a Kerberized Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hive, kerberos, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have Apache NiFi running standalone and its working fine. But, when I am trying to **setup Apache NiFi to access Hive or HDFS** Kerberized Cloudera Hadoop Cluster. I am getting issues.

Can someone guide me on the documentation for Setting HDFS/Hive/HBase (with Kerberos)

Here is the configuration I gave in **nifi.properties**

```
# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=/etc/krb5.conf
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=pseeram@JUNIPER.COM
nifi.kerberos.keytab.location=/uhome/pseeram/learning/pseeram.keytab
nifi.kerberos.authentication.expiration=10 hours
```

[image]

I referenced various links like, but none of those are helpful.
(Since the below link said it had issues in NiFi 0.7.1 version, I tried NiFi 1.1.0 version. I had the same bitter experience)
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/62014/nifi-hive-connection-pool-error.html
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4103/hiveserver2-jdbc-connection-url-examples.html

Here are the errors I am getting logs:

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.nifi.processors.hive.SelectHiveQL 
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://ddas1106a:10000/innovate: Peer indicated failure: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool.getConnection(HiveConnectionPool.java:292) ~[nifi-hive-processors-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceProvider$1.invoke(StandardControllerServiceProvider.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.SelectHiveQL.onTrigger(SelectHiveQL.java:158) ~[nifi-hive-processors-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://ddas1106a:10000/innovate: Peer indicated failure: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool.getConnection(HiveConnectionPool.java:288) ~[nifi-hive-processors-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://ddas1106a:10000/innovate: Peer indicated failure: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:231) ~[hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:176) ~[hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105) ~[hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Peer indicated failure: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:199) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:307) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:204) ~[hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    ... 27 common frames omitted


WARN [NiFi Web Server-29] o.a.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool HiveConnectionPool[id=278beb67-0159-1000-cffa-8c8534c285c8] Configuration does not have security enabled, Keytab and Principal will be ignored
```

Comment: These properties are clearly useful when you want to **Kerberize your own NiFi cluster**, but have nothing to do with accessing a Kerberized external resource like HDFS or Hive *(except for the `krb5.conf` path which is global)*.

Comment: For HDFS, see https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/456/i-have-nifi-setup-on-my-cluster-but-it-only-works.html

Comment: For Hive, **just read the documentation from top to bottom** https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool/

Answer (score 1):

What you've added in nifi.properties file is useful for Kerberizing nifi cluster. In order to access kerberized hadoop cluster, you need to provide appropriate config files and keytabs in NiFi's HDFS processor.

For example, if you are using putHDFS to write to a Hadoop cluster:

Hadoop Configuration Resources :  paths to core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Kerberos Principal: Your principal to access hadoop cluster

kerberos keytab: Path to keytab generated using krb5.conf of hadoop cluster. nifi.kerberos.krb5.file in nifi.properties must be pointed to appropriate krb5.conf file.

Immaterial of whether NiFi is inside kerberized hadoop cluster or not, this post might be useful.
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/84659/how-to-use-apache-nifi-on-kerberized-hdp-cluster-n.html